# Creating a function to add a calculated column to a table in SQL Server based on a query

Tags: sql-server, function

I have 2 database tables called `Spend`, and `VendorSpend`. The columns used in the Spend table are called `VendorID, VendorName, RecordDate, and Charges`. The VendorSpend table contains `VendorID` and `VendorName` but with distinct data `(one record for each unique VendorID)`. I need a simple way to add a column to the `VendorSpend` table called `Aug2015`, this column will contain the `SUM of each Vendor's charges within that month time period`. It will be calculated based on this query:

```
Select Sum(Charges) 
  from Spend
  where RecordDate >= '2015-08-01' and RecordDate <= '2015-08-31'
```

Keep in mind this will need to be called whenever new data is inserted into the Spend table and the VendorSpend table will need to update based on the new data. This will happen every month so actually a new column will need to be added and the data be calculated every month.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like very bad table's design... If you are going like this, you'll be asking for help with PIVOT and UNPIVOT within weeks ;-)    How man data rows are there? Which sql server version are you using?

Comment: The tables are indeed bad, it is basically just a dump of a very large spreadsheet we receive every month. Currently in the Spend table there are over 22,000 records. SSMS 2014

Answer (score 0):

Create a user-defined function that you pass a VendorID and Date to and which does your SELECT:

```
Select Sum(Charges) 
  from Spend
  where VendorID=@VendorID
 AND DATEDIFF(month, RecordDate, @Date) = 0
```

Now personally, I would stop right there and use the function to select your data at query time, rather than adding a new column to your table.

But treating your question as academic, you can create a computed column called [Aug2015] in VendorSpend that passes [VendorID] and '08/01/2015' to this function and it will contain the desired result.

Comment: I am almost brand new to SQL but I am picking it up fast. Could you provide the syntax for how to create this function and how to call it when I need to create a new column?

Comment: Please google SQL CREATE FUNCTION.   The answers to these questions are already freely available on the internet.

Comment: I successfully created the function and it calculates the correct sum but I am still hard coding the VendorID and the Date when I call it. I need it to cycle down the VendorSpend table, look at the VendorID, and input the sum of charges for each vendor ID in the new column. Thoughts?

Comment: This is what a computed column does for you automatically.   Again, google SQL COMPUTED COLUMN FUNCTION.   There are plenty of examples already on the internet.